# PHP string is giving syntax error

Tags: php, string

Why am I getting this type of error in this string:

```
$query="SELECT Name,Lastname FROM $_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'] s,
     WHERE s.FK_ID_user={$id_user}
     AND DATE(s.time) BETWEEN '".$d_year1."-".$d_month1."-".$d_day1."' AND '".$d_year2."-".$d_month2."-".$d_day2."'";
```

Comment: Remove teh quotes from the array keys. When using arrays in a double-quoted string, the quoted keys will issue warnings. That or switch to the `{}` encapsulation notation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
 $query="SELECT Name,Lastname FROM $_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'] s,
```

With

```
$query="SELECT Name,Lastname FROM {$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']} s,
```

Better Still

```
$query= "SELECT Name,Lastname FROM %s s, WHERE s.FK_ID_user= '%d' AND DATE(s.time) BETWEEN '%d-%d-%d' AND '%d-%d-%d'";
$query = sprintf($query,$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'],$id_user,$d_year1 ,$d_month1,$d_day1,$d_year2,$d_month2,$d_day2);
```

Comment: I am still getting error on this place: `WHERE s.FK_ID_user= '' `

Comment: I checked that I am receiving a number as value `$id_user` but error still persists

Comment: With `%d` I am getting only 0 (zero)

Comment: What is the value of `var_dump($_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'])`

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question or error above .... `PHP string is giving syntax error`

Comment: If you are having new issues ... make it a new question and add the link here .. would surely assist

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']
```

to

```
{$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']}
```

$_SESSION is becoming blank because the [] is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$query="SELECT Name,Lastname FROM {$_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE']} s, ";
$query.="WHERE s.FK_ID_user={$id_user}";
$query.="AND DATE(s.time) BETWEEN '".$d_year1."-".$d_month1."-".$d_day1."' AND";
$query.="'".$d_year2."-".$d_month2."-".$d_day2."'";
```

Comment: Pointless. This changes nothing and just makes things a little harder to read. I won't -1 since you did put in the `{}`, which will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query="SELECT Name,Lastname FROM $_SESSION['SESS_MAIN_BASE'] s,
     WHERE s.FK_ID_user=$id_user
     AND DATE(s.time) BETWEEN '$d_year1-$d_month1-$d_day1' AND '$d_year2-$d_month2-$d_day2'";
```